# Why do some users stop receiving firebase notifications?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

For most cases our firebase notification system works pretty well. Our app is written in Dart (Flutter) and works on iOS as well as Android. We use the firebase_messaging.dart package.

However, a few users stop receiving push notification at some time. In most cases, restarting the app/restarting the phone will fix this problem. Is this a common problem, and is there a fix for this problem?

Thank you for your help!

Merijn

This is the code where configure the firebaseMessaging part:

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('in message');
        doingNotification=true;
        appState.onNotification=true;
        appState.typeNotification='onMessaging';
        _doQuestionnaire(message,true,true,true);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        doingNotification=true;
        print('in resume');
        appState.typeNotification='onResume';
        appState.onNotification=true;
        _doQuestionnaire(message,false,true,false);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        doingNotification=true;
        print('in launch');
        appState.typeNotification='onLaunch';
        appState.onNotification=true;
        _doQuestionnaire(message,false,false,false);
      },
    );
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this?